# Meteor server side. Calling http request inside .then

Tags: javascript, meteor, promise

I need to build api method with meteor that should immediately return OK and request a webhook after the long work is done.

The sample code looks like this

```js
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
let Promise = require('bluebird');

Meteor.startup(() => {
  Picker.route('/', (params, req, res, next) => {
    getAnimalName = Promise.promisify( (cb) => {
        setTimeout( () => {
            cb(null, "porcupine");
        }, 1000);
    })()

    getAnimalName.then( (name) => {
        HTTP.get('https://www.google.ru/#q='+name, (err, res) => {
            if(! err){
                console.log(res);
            }
        });
    } );

    res.end("OK");
  });
});
```

As result I get this error

```
W20160704-02:14:10.908(3)? (STDERR) Unhandled rejection Error: Meteor code must always run within a Fiber. Try wrapping callbacks that you pass to non-Meteor libraries with Meteor.bindEnvironment.
W20160704-02:14:10.908(3)? (STDERR)     at Object.Meteor._nodeCodeMustBeInFiber (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:9:1)
W20160704-02:14:10.909(3)? (STDERR)     at Object.Meteor.bindEnvironment (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:85:1)
W20160704-02:14:10.909(3)? (STDERR)     at Object.call (packages/meteor/helpers.js:117:1)
W20160704-02:14:10.909(3)? (STDERR)     at Object.HTTP.get (packages/http/httpcall_common.js:50:20)
W20160704-02:14:10.909(3)? (STDERR)     at server/main.js:14:10
W20160704-02:14:10.910(3)? (STDERR)     at [object Object]._onTimeout (server/main.js:8:6)
W20160704-02:14:10.910(3)? (STDERR)     at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:121:15)
W20160704-02:14:10.910(3)? (STDERR) From previous event:
W20160704-02:14:10.911(3)? (STDERR)     at server/main.js:12:18
W20160704-02:14:10.911(3)? (STDERR)     at doCall (packages/meteorhacks_picker/packages/meteorhacks_picker.js:106:1)
```

I tried different things like wrapping `HTTP.get` to `Fiber`, wrapping callback to `Meteor.bindEnvironment` and several meteor packages for promises. And the error was the same. Is there a way how to make a http request inside promise's `.then`? (Big part of my code is already written in terms of promises and I don't want to refactor it in Fiber or whatever). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue with Bluebird and Meteor.  The issue is timeouts.

If you use timeouts, use [`Meteor.setTimeout()`](http://docs.meteor.com/api/timers.html#Meteor-setTimeout) or [`Meteor.bindEnvironment()`](https://guide.meteor.com/using-npm-packages.html#bind-environment).

Your own timeouts must be revised.  There is also the issue that Bluebird uses `setTimeout()` internally.  `Bluebird.promisify()` seems to work OK, but you may be better off just using the in-built Promise polyfill that comes with Meteor.

Here's a promisify replacement you can use:

```
function promisify( fn, options ){
  return function(){
    options = Object.assign( {
      context: this,
      multiArgs: false
    }, options );

    let slice = ( arr, i, j ) => Array.prototype.slice.call( arr, i, j );

    let args = slice( arguments );

    return new Promise(( resolve, reject ) => {
      let callback = ( err, val ) => {
        if( err != null ){
          reject( err );
        } else {
          resolve( options.multiArgs ? slice( arguments, 1 ) : val );
        }
      };

      args.push( callback );

      fn.apply( options.context, args );
    });
  };
}
```